# Cordova project is not running in emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, phonegap

I am using Cordova 5.0.0. I want to run my Cordova project in the emulator. I am using the latest android studio for using an emulator. my sdk is also latest. If I run the command. `cordova emulate --target=emulator-5554 android` The app is not running on the emulator. There is not showing any error. when I using this command `emulator -list-avds` It shows the list. But not running the app on the emulator. How to run the app on the emulator. please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cordova run android
```

It will automatically run in your emulator.

Comment: not working. I have tried different times. But not working. Please help me.

Comment: ohhk. Then try with genymotion.

Comment: No, Its free too.
You will not get some functionality. But its available free.

Comment: genymotion is not running in my desktop. It shows installation have some problems.

Comment: which error are you facing ?
Please follow https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/01_Get_Started/Installation.htm this installation for install genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

The console should update as the project is built and deployed to the emulator. You should see something there describing that it either did deploy the app to the emulator or errors if it didn't. Review the console output and look for errors.